# Restore WhatsApp Data from Internal Storage on Moving to a New Phone

Tags: applications, backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I have WhatsApp installed on my old Phone.
WhatsApp is backup both to Google Drive and to the local storage.
The Google Drive backup is for text chat and images only (The default).
The local backup includes everything (Audio, Video, Documents, etc...).

I want to move all my WhatsApp data to my new phone.
Usually it will be done as following:

1. Copy all files of the WhatsApp folder from the old phone to the new phone.
2. Install WhatsApp on the new phone.
3. Start WhatsApp on the new phone and when asked for restoring data click restore.

#### The Problem

The restoration process of WhatsApp will restore information from Google Drive and not from the local storage.

How can one force WhatsApp to restore all data from the local storage?

Comment: Local backup includes everything? Do you mean the entire Whatsapp folder or the msgstore.crypt file? I thought the latter only backed up text chats while the rest are just present in the other folders.

Comment: Yea. They are present in the other folders. But I assume the `msgstore.crypt` in the local folder includes links to those (On the chats) while the online doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your local files all, databases and images.

First deactivate google drive.

1. Open google drive.
2. Top left menu, backups, **deactivate** Google Drive WhatsApp backup

(option to delete also, not necessary)

Copy all files over to WhatsApp folder on phone

4. Re-do the login procedure as usual.

In theory that's it.